# If $M,N$ D-modules, $ann(M \oplus N)=\langle c\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

> If $M,N$ are D-modules, where $D$ is a PID and $Ann(M)=\langle a\rangle, Ann(N)=\langle b\rangle$, $a\neq 0 \neq b$. Prove that $Ann(M \oplus N)=\langle c\rangle$ where $c=\gcd(a,b)$.

Does the statement makes sense? Every element in $Ann(M \oplus N)$ is of the form $(m,n)$, making it strange to claim that it is generated by $\gcd(a,b)$.

Or should I understand it as Ann set giving the $c$ elements such that $c(m,n)=0$? Because in the latter case $c(m,n)=(cm,cn)$ and since the annihilators of $M,N$ are generated by $a,b$ then $c=a^p, c=b^q$ with $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$. But I can't conclude $c$ must be $\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: It's not true .

Comment: How will you define gcd in any ring? I think it should be euclidean domain which can have gcd in two elements.

Comment: Even if you take modules over trivial rings which are UFD or some kind of ring which follow gcd and lcm then lcm(a,b) should work always.

Comment: @shrinit I forgot to add $D$ is a PID.

Comment: @Cure thanks and  lcm should always work as one can see easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $M$ and $N$ have annihilators $I$ and $J$ then
$M\oplus N$ has annihilator $I\cap J$. To prove that note that
elements of $I\cap J$ do annihilate $M\oplus N$, and if $a$
annihilates $M\oplus N$ is must annihilate $M\oplus\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\oplus N$ and so also $M$ and $N$.

In a PID, if $I=\left<a\right>$ and $J=\left<b\right>$ with $ab\ne0$
then $I\cap J=\left<c\right>$ where $c$ is a *least common multiple*
of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "In general", can it be false then?

Comment: @Cure Can what be false?

Comment: You said, "*In general*, if M,n have annihilataros I, J, then $M\oplus N$ has annihilator $I\cap J$." It might be an idiomatic thing fo my language, as we use "in general" to denote "almost always".

Comment: @Cure So you are asking whether the theorem I stated, and whose proof I outlined, is false?

Comment: Why did this answer got a -1? Just asking, I wonder if someone saw something wrong here.